# In pyzmq, how do you stop a Proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a server behind a firewall and a publicly available web server requesting info from the server.  I am using pyzmq to manage the communication between the backend and the web front end.  This work without a proxy in place, when they are communicating locally.  It works when using the proxy.  I can start up a ThreadProxy, but how do I stop it?

```
import zmq
from zmq.devices import ThreadProxy

class MyProxy:
    def __init__(self)
        p = ThreadProxy(zmq.ROUTER, zmq.DEALER) # Not using mon
        p.setsockopt_in(zmq.IDENTITY, b'ROUTER')
        p.setsockopt_out(zmq.IDENTITY, b'DEALER')
        p.bind_in('tcp://*:5550')
        p.connect_out('tcp://localhost:5550')
        self._proxy = p
    def start(self)
        self._proxy.start()
    def stop(self)
        ???
```

How do I actually ask that proxy to stop? .join just waits, because the proxy is blocked or has no reason to stop.  I don't have a context to .term().

I would like to run this inside a linux daemon, so "kill" is not the most elegant solution, nor does it give me the control over the proxy I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the proxy closes itself.

I think my problem was one of understanding.  The proxy is being started as a daemon (the default) and I did not know what that meant to Python.  When all non-daemon threads finish, the program ends.  What that means in this context is that the proxy stops when the rest of my program stops. I do not need to explicitly stop it.

As I am building an Linux service, this is precisely the functionality I want.  In the main thread, I will kick off the proxy, do something (like monitor the proxy) or nothing, and when I want to the service to stop, the main thread will wrap up, close and the proxy will die on it's own.

Comment: Assuming Proxy behaves the same as a normal Device, it dies when it's context closes. Doing something like `myProxy.context_factory().term()` will eventually stop the proxy manually, though letting garbage collection do that for you works fine, too.